# expected primary-expression before '<' token error

Tags: c++

Hi I am going back through C programming exercises and in this particular program I get an expected primary-expression before '<' token at Line 8 (The While loop). Would appreciate some clarification on what I would need to fix and the reasoning behind it. Here is the code and thank you so much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int number, i=8;
   cout <<"Please enter all numbers from 8-23\n";
   cout <<"Start Now: ";
   while (i=<23){
          cin>>number;
          cout<<"Next: ";
          if (number!=i){
             cout<<"That was the wrong, Please enter: "<<i<<endl;
          }
         else 
           i++;
    }
    cout<<"Congratulations!!\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The relational operators are ==, !=, <, >, <=, and >=.  There is no => or =< operator (in C/C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> while (i=<23){
>         ^^
> ```

Try `while (i <= 23)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`while (i=<23){` should be `while(i<=23){`